# Cathy’s Composite party is powered by three Prime Pals. Can you find them?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

Given:

A, B, C are 3 distinct primes.

Find the smallest composite number Y that satisfies the relation:

$ Y  =  A ^ C + B ^ B  + C ^ A $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The goal is to minimize, so you'll need to obviously use the primes

> $2, 3, 5$

Then

> The $5$ can't be in the middle as $5^5$ is large, so it must be on either side. $(2^5 + 3^3) < (3^5 + 2^2)$, so your equation is $2^5 + 3^3 + 5^2$.

This means

> $(A, B, C) = (2, 3, 5)$ and $Y = 84$

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree with the answer given by @Aranlyde.

> But you don't explicitly specify that $A\not=B\not=C$.
>  So, I would do something like $A=B=C=2$.
>  Then, the result would be:
>
>  $Y=A^C+B^B+C^A=2^2+2^2+2^2=4+4+4=12$
>
>  In any way, this is the minimum.

Comment: Three prime pals refer to three different..i will edit to add distinct..thx

Comment: Okay, well. Then my answer is incorrect, of course. :)